# Correct terminology for minting?

Tags: terminology, mint

I am creating a contract such that for every wallet owner there is a "special" set of tokens that he can send to other wallets in unlimited quantifies (even if having zero or little of this token on his own account).

How is this operation (of tokens appearing of nowhere) called? Is it "minting"?

But doesn't minting mean tokens to appear on my own account? I instead send tokens to somebody's other account. So is it indeed minting?

What could be a suitable method name in this operation? Are `mint` or `mintFor` good names for this method? If not, give ideas how to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minting is typically the operation of creating tokens from nothing. It doesn't really matter where the tokens end up - whether in your own account, stay in the contract's address or are assigned to someone else.

Actually when you mint tokens you can directly assign them to any address so you don't have to "send" them anywhere. Furthermore there is never any actual "sending" as it's only shuffling numbers inside the token contract (reducing balance for one address and increasing for another - or in the case of minting just simply increasing the balance of any address).